# How to verify that my firebase application is the one calling my API?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase web app calling my Python API.

the user who is using my app does not need to login to use it but I still need to make sure that this request coming from my application

How can I verify the identity of the app sending the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to enforce that calls can only come from your application. In a database that is directly accessible from the internet, that is simply not possible. Anyone who can use your web app, can take the configuration data from that app and use the Firebase API to make their own calls.

That's why it's important that you enforce all business rules that you have for your database in Firebase's server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) too. You can use these to enforce data structure, and (when combined with Firebase Authentication) ensure that all data access is authorized.

You can use Firebase Authentication without requiring your users to enter credentials by using [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth). This essentially gives your user a unique ID, that you can then use to identify that user (and the data they create) in security rules.